# jQuery UI modal dialog captures all keypress so I can't input text inside it

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I create modal dialog with form inside it (with some text input).
And I just can't enter the text inside the textbox. Dialog blocks keyboard input.

Here is my simplified example:

```
<div id="modal-dialog">
    <label for="my-text">TRY to input text...</label>
    <textarea id="my-text" style="position:relative; z-index:1"></textarea>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialog = $('#modal-dialog').dialog({ modal: true });
</script>
```

*Note*: You may ask - why did I mentioned about `"position:relative; z-index:1"`? Because it works fine without it. But I can't remove it because of design.

*Note*: **not modal** dialog works fine too.

*I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 + jQuery UI 1.8.14*

Comment: Have you try to remove the style in the textarea? Just for the fun of it. The modal functionality is a z-index div above the rest of the document. It might just be that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The z-index is the problem. Here is an exemple ( http://jsfiddle.net/c3BPP/ ) of your code with a bigger z-index and it  works.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But it seems like jQuery UI bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can also lower the z-index of the JQuery dialog:

```
var dialog = $('#modal-dialog').dialog({ 
    modal: true,
    zIndex: 500
});
```

By default, it is 1000.  Of course your relative or absolute positioned elements needing text input need to be greater than the z-index of the dialog still.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `<form>` tag in my dialog was getting a `z-index` of 1, preventing any of the controls from working.  Instead of changing the `z-index` for each control, simply changing the `z-index` of the `<form>` tag to 1010 (a value higher than the default of the dialog) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `tabindex="-1"` helped me resolve this problem.

Here's an example:

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="error" role="dialog">
```

Comment: You seem to have posted before finishing what you were writing. Where should OP put this attribute? What does it do?