# jquery dialog issue in firefox: can't type after opens 1st time

Tags: jquery, firefox, focus, jquery-ui-dialog

My jquery dialog doesn't work correctly in Firefox, but Firebug doesn't give me any errors. My dialog works perfectly fine in Chrome.

**Situation:**
I have several jquery dialogs on my page that open up on different events. One "Add New Element" dialog is giving me a problem. It worked fine the first time the dialog opened. Any subsequent times, the text input box couldn't be clicked on or typed in. I THOUGHT I fixed the problem by destroying the dialog each time. Then it worked every time you opened it up. But then I discovered if any other dialog is opened and then this "Add New Element" dialog is opened, the same thing happens again: Can't type in the box.

I am baffled!!!! Please, any help would be greatly appreciated... I've been staring at this code for days now.

Here is jquery dialog code:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-new-osc-el" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height:300,
        width:400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create": function() {

*create button function stuff here* then:

            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    create_new_osc_el_dialog();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                create_new_osc_el_dialog();
            }
        },
            close: function() {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                create_new_osc_el_dialog();
            }
    });
});
```

And the dialog is opened when the "add new element" div is clicked on - the div has an onclick function:

```
<div class="addnewbox" onclick="addneweltoosc();">
```

This onclick function looks like this (with some code removed for brevity):

```
    function addneweltoosc(){
                $( "#dialog-new-osc-el" ).dialog( "open" );
}
```

The actual HTML for the dialog is quite long, here is the important stuff:

```
<div id="dialog-new-osc-el" title="Create Element">

<div id="new_osc_el_type" class="pointer">
<ul>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Branch');">Branch</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Group');">Group</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Division');">Division</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Unit');">Unit</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Strike Team');">Strike Team</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Task Force');">Task Force</li>
<li onclick="new_osc_el_type_chosen('Individual Resource');">Individual Resource</li>
</ul>
</div>
<p><input class="hide" type="text" id="new_osc_el_pos_name" />
</div>
```

The dialog first gives users a list to select from. When the user clicks on a list item, the new_osc_el_type_chosen function is called. This function hides that list and shows the "new_osc_el_pos_name" text input. **This is the input box that works the first time the dialog opens, but not after.** This is the code:

```
function new_osc_el_type_chosen(a)

{
$("#new_osc_el_type").addClass("hide");
$("#new_osc_el_pos_name").removeClass("hide");
if (a=="Branch")
{
$("#new_osc_el_pos_name").val("NAME of Branch Director");
}
document.getElementById("new_osc_el_pos_name").setSelectionRange(0,7);
$("#new_osc_el_pos_name").focus();
}
```

**SOLVED!**

Apparently all the dialogs being modal was causing a conflict amongst them... or something. Actually, I'm not 100% sure why - but changing modal:true to modal:false solved my problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue twice, each with its own fix (IIRC). The first time was when I was using jQuery UI's dialog (and I needed to use modal:true) and I believe the problem had to do with a conflicting z-index property (my inputs were too low).  The second time was with a homebrew modal-ish element, and that was because I was testing out .disableSelection() on an affected input and had forgotten to take that out.

Comment: Had the same problem! So annoying! Setting modal:false worked for me also, but I didn't want to cave in so see my answer below for a solution that fixed this for me, and still gives the modal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same annoying problem with Firefox. All other browsers worked great.

I noticed the problem on pages that had more than one dialog defined (all are defined with `autoOpen: false`, so they do not open until a user clicks a button that triggers `dialog("open")`

I had two simple dialogs, each with a single `input type="text"` and with two buttons (`input type="button"`, for "Cancel" and "OK").

I could reproduce by using either dialog, but a simple test worked with one dialog:

1. Open a dialog. I could type text into the input box just fine the first time.
2. Close the dialog via clicking the X in top right.
3. Open the same dialog from #1. In all browsers EXCEPT Firefox I could type in the box just fine. In firefox everything LOOKED OK (the modal layer was behind the dialog, but in front of everything else), but simply didn't work.

I tried increasing the z-index of the input and its dialog div. I tried decreasing the z-index of the modal layer. I even deleted the modal div element. These had no effect. Then I searched for "modal" within jquery-ui.js (was using jQuery UI - v1.9.2) and found this section to be the problem (I confirmed that by commenting it out the input problem went away).

**Source of problem, from jquery-ui.js (1.9.2):**

```
// adjust the maxZ to allow other modal dialogs to continue to work (see #4309)
if ( this.options.modal ) {
    maxZ = 0;
    $( ".ui-dialog" ).each(function() {
        if ( this !== that.uiDialog[0] ) {
            thisZ = $( this ).css( "z-index" );
            if ( !isNaN( thisZ ) ) {
                maxZ = Math.max( maxZ, thisZ );
            }
        }
    });
    $.ui.dialog.maxZ = maxZ;
}
```

I found #4309 on the jQuery UI bug tracker : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4309

It appears the issue was fixed for all browsers, but the problem remained in Firefox (at least in the version I'm using) - and now occurs even if you open/close/reopen only one of the dialogs (so the other dialogs were there, but never had "open" called on them).

**The hack fix that worked for me was to do this after loading jquery-ui.js:**

```
if ($.browser.mozilla)
{
    // fix firefox z-index bug with modal jquery UI dialog that prevents user from typing after initial modal dialog opened
    $.fn.dialogOriginal = $.fn.dialog; // save original dialog() function
    $.fn.dialog = function ()
    {
        if (!$(this).data("fixModalZIndex"))
        {
            // bind events only once
            $(this).data("fixModalZIndex", true).bind("dialogbeforeclose", function (event, ui)
            {
                // unhook modal behavior to fix firefox bug
                $(this).dialog("option", "modal", false);
            }).bind("dialogclose", function (event, ui)
            {
                var ref = $(this); // save reference for later
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    ref.dialog("option", "modal", true); // set back to modal, but in a timeout to avoid the z-index input bug
                    ref = null;
                }, 0);
            });
        }
        return $.fn.dialogOriginal.apply(this, arguments); // call original dialog function
    };
}
```

Don't really understand this one. Would probably help to debug through the maxZ logic, but I'm not a Firefox fan and since my hack fix worked I was ready to close this ticket and go back to fixing my own bugs instead of fixing jQuery's. Hope this info helps somebody, sounds like you already decided to go the modal:false route (which also worked for me, but the client really wanted it modal...)

Comment: Thank you so much your hack/fix worked. I spent a couple hours trying to figure it out and you saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

- Destroy then close seems odd as an order of operations.
- the `create_new_osc_el_dialog()` function seems like it might be pertinent
- the fact that you have quotes around "Create" but not Cancel seems odd, and with the indentation as it is, I can't quite tell whether your `{}`s are in the right places.

Does the error occur if you have a different dialog open and then open "Add New Element" for the first time, or is it only in cases where you've opened and closed "Add New Element" and also have another dialog open?

Jquery dialog and firefox have apparently had a number of issues over the years.  What versions of JQuery and Firefox are you using?

I have heard a suggestion for a similar problem that you try setting the dialog div to `style="position:fixed"`, but I don't know whether that will solve your particular incarnation of this problem.

Comment: create_new_osc_el_dialog() was the function to recreate the dialog again after I destroyed it. I don't even know any more I tried so many things to get it it work! ;p I've never had an issue with jquery and firefox before... strange. Anyhow, I've solved it, by pure accident. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well, it turned out to be a `z-index` issue when the `modal` overlay has a higher `z-index` than the `textbox`.

Thanks to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949059/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-captures-all-keypress-so-i-cant-input-text-inside-it) I quickly found out why and was able to resolve my issue.